# how to insert php into jquery append via ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have checked a few posts about "How to insert PHP into jQuery?" but don't seem to find what I am want.
I am not sure if this will work but I do have a todo list in php and I am trying to implement ajax into it.
in ajax upon success I want to appened

```
<a href="done.php?as=done&item=<?php echo $item['id']; ?>" class="done-button">Done</a>
```

but somehow I am stuck at the php part.
This is what I have inside my script

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function(e){
        var todoText = $("input[name='todoText']").val();
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "add-ajax.php",
            data: {todoText : todoText},
            success: function(){
                $('p.empty').empty();
                $('input.input').val('');
                $('ul.items').append('<li>'+todoText+'<a href="#" class="done-button">Done</a></li>');
            }
        })
    });
});
```

the append here works but when I am trying to add the php in it, it wouldn't work.

EDIT (the errors I get):

let's say if I put the whole line

```
$('ul.items').append('<li>'+todoText+'<a href="done.php?as=done&item=<?php echo $item["id"]; ?>" class="done-button">Done</a></li>');
```

the error I get from firefox is

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
$('ul.items').append('<li>'+todoText+'<a href="done.php?as=done&item=<br />
```

In chrome I get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

My Html:

```
        <ul class="items">
            <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
                <li>
                    <span class="item<?php echo $item['done'] ? ' done' : '' ?>">
                        <?php echo $item['todoText']; ?>
                    </span>
                    <?php if($item['done']): ?>
                        <a href="delete.php?as=delete&item=<?php echo $item['id']; ?>" class="delete-button">Delete Task</a>
                    <?php endif; ?> 
                    <?php if(!$item['done']): ?>
                      <a href="done.php?as=done&item=<?php echo $item['id']; ?>" class="done-button">Done</a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I want the ajax to return pretty much the same thing as my html where I can click the done button.

my add-ajax.php

```
require_once 'app/init.php';

if (isset($_POST['todoText']))
{
$todoText = htmlentities(trim($_POST['todoText']), ENT_QUOTES);

if (!empty($todoText))
{


    $addedQuery = $db->prepare("
            INSERT INTO todoitems (todoText, user, done, created)
            VALUES (:todoText, :user, 0, NOW())
        ");
```

Comment: Explain the 'id doesn`t work' part, open the console of your browser and check if there are javascript errors or php (within the response)

Comment: what doesn't work?  What do you see after you append the PHP?  Just raw text rather than the echoed value?

Comment: View the source of your page ... You'll notice you have `$('ul.items').append('<li>'+todoText+'<a href="done.php?as=done&item=<br />` ... The `<br />` is telling me that you have a PHP error ... The page source will have the full error

Comment: ah, I see it can't find the item variable by any chance I can use php to loop through? actually let me edit my post again.  I should have shown what's in the html.

Comment: In your situation, I would make `add-ajax.php` return what I want to append as a data (that will be passed to my success handler)..question of separating client from server

Comment: Answer of Marcos Dimitrio is detailing more the approach i suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return the "id" as a JSON to your AJAX call.

In your "add-ajax.php":

```
$returnValue = array("id"=>$id);
exit(json_encode($returnValue));
```

In your AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "add-ajax.php",
    dataType: "json", // type of data that you're expecting back from the server
    data: {todoText : todoText}
})
.done(function(data) {
    $('p.empty').empty();
    $('input.input').val('');
    $('ul.items').append(
        '<li>' + todoText + 
        '<a href="done.php?as=done&item=' + data.id + 
        '" class="done-button">Done</a></li>'
    );
});
```

Comment: ah ok, but in my `add-ajax.php` it's a php script inserting those data into the database.  Do I have run a loop query to find the right id? or there is a faster way to do it? I edited and added my add-ajax.php

Comment: If you're using PDO, you can use [`PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php), like this: `$id = $db->lastInsertId();`.

Comment: thanks thanks a lot! first time doing ajax myself. It's fun~ let me see if I can do a delete button myself with ajax too :D thx thx again